# Not able to save LinearLayout values to xml file

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

Developing an android app here I am dynamically generating `EditText` and button like `Call` and `Remove` from row.xml file. adding these control to `LinearLayout` I implemented as I want but my problem is that I want to save the `EditText` values into xml file. so that next time I open this app the particular values gets populated from xml file.

[image]

Adding name and Mobile number to TextBox  and click on `"Add"` button these values are dynamically added to `LinearLayout`. when I click on Add this values are stored into xml file and whenever next time I launch the app stored xml values are populated into `LinearLayout`.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        EditText textIn, txtPhoneNo;
        Button buttonAdd;
        LinearLayout container;
        EditText textOut;
        System.Collections.ArrayList arrList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            textIn = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textin);
            txtPhoneNo = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPhoneNo);
            buttonAdd = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.add);
            container = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.container);
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
            View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, null);
            textOut = (EditText)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textout);
            arrList.Add(txtPhoneNo.Text);
            if (textIn.Text != "" && txtPhoneNo.Text != "")
            {
                textOut.SetText(textIn.Text + " : " + txtPhoneNo.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                container.AddView(addView);
                Button btnCall = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnCall);
                btnCall.Click += BtnCall_Click;
                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.remove);
                buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Field can not be blank.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        private void BtnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           string strNo = After(textOut.Text,":");
            callDialog.SetMessage("Call " + strNo + "?");
            callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Call", delegate
            {
                 var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
                callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + strNo));
                StartActivity(callIntent);
            });
            callDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { });

            // Show the alert dialog to the user and wait for response.
            callDialog.Show();
        }
}
}

Main.axml


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="name" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="345.0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="Phone No." />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Add" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
row.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/remove"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Remove"/>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnCall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remove"
      android:text="Call"/>
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/textout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/remove"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't**

you cannot store controls dynamically into your `xml` layout.
Either you add it manually into `xml` or you can create separate `xml` for control and then `include` it `xml` into your parent `xml`

```
<include 
  android:layout="id of your layout"
//height ... width
/>
```

In both ways, you have to create `xml`.

We are creating `xml` and inflate it in our `java` class. what you want to do is totally reverse of that.

**Update**

*use shared preference*

```
SharedPreference shared= context.getSharedPreferences("your preference name",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String value = shared.getString("UserPhone","no data");

//set this value to your control
```

Comment: I am storing the control dynamically I just want to store the its values.

Comment: so store it in shared preference and when you create your dynamic view set old value from shared preferences.

Comment: here I am saving to shared preference folder                     edit.PutString("UserName", textIn.Text.Trim());
 edit.PutString("UserPhone", txtPhoneNo.Text.Trim());
 edit.Apply(); with this code but how I can get it back when reopening the app next time

Comment: I am not able to see any shared preference logic

Comment: check my answer @MartinP

Comment: thanks for reply. Can I stored more than one values in SharedPreferences like List object

Comment: in the above screen shot how can i do that? to store multiple name and number and get retrieve back

Comment: sorry my friends imgur is blocked here . I cant see any images

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer `SharedPreferences` in android. This will serve your purpose.

Comment: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-androids-sharedpreferences-to-save-data.html.. example

Comment: Can I stored more than one values in SharedPreferences like List object

Comment: No.. it takes only strings. it meant to be store key value pairs.

well i would rather suggest go with serialization of objects and file storage.
another approach i can suggest is check GSON nice frame work most will go this one.
or u can use json.